# Chronoforms v5 - Content Plugin - Captcha will not validated

Tags: plugins, captcha, chronoforms

I'm having big problems with the Chronoforms V5 - Content Plugin for Joomla.
If I send the form without integrating it in an article the Captcha will validated correctly, but if I use the Content-Plugin in an article, everytime the message "The entered verification code is wrong" appears.

Maybe one of you can help me????

Answer (score 1):

If you have caching on then an older version of the form may be served and the token in that will not match to the current user. In that case you need to use one of the anti-spam methods that does not rely on a matched token like a Google captcha.

If there is more than one form in the page and you have Relative URL set to Yes then the form may be submitting to the 'other' form URL - this would also give a mismatched token.